# Conditions for which the sum of the product of sequences diverges

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(C_k)_{k=1}^{\infty} \geq 0$ be non-decreasing sequence of natural numbers. I am trying to figure out when does the sum $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} C_k 2^{-k} $$ diverge. From my understanding $C_k$ should be something of the form $2^{k}$ as we need to kill the decay of geometric series. Initially I thought $C_k$ ~ $2^k$ but then I can have $\frac{2^k} {k}$ which diverges and is not comparable with $2^{k}$.

Any suggestions on lower bounds of $C_k$ would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply the ratio or the root test and get the sufficient conditions for absolute convergence $\limsup |C_{k+1}/C_k| <2$ and $\limsup\sqrt[k]{|C_k|}<2$, respectively.

Comment: Isn't the ratio supposed to be 1?

Comment: Well, here we have $a_k = C_k2^{-k}$.

Comment: aah yes, I see..

Answer (score 0):

I think the [ratio test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/RatioTest.aspx) would do the trick:

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=L$$

The series diverges for $L>1$. For a more general case where the limit doesn't exist $\lim\inf\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|>1$ is a sufficient condition for divergence.